# How to validate PAN No and Bank account number using php?

Tags: php, drupal, civicrm

I need to validate pan number and bank account number fields. How can I do that using php?
I have to implement this validation in civicrm custom form. civicrm has any built in function for these two validations.

Comment: pan= "permanent account number" in india? There's far too many TLAs these days...

Comment: Do you mean 'validate' as in "make sure it's formatted correctly" or validate as in "check with the bank to make sure the account is legitimate". The former is merely difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pan number validation regular expression

```
if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/", $pannumber)) {
  echo "Invalid pan number";
}
```

Comment: This validates the alphanumeric structure of the PAN. But there is more. The last character of the first set of characters need to be the initial character of the last name of the account holder.