# How to validate tin and cst using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to validate India's Taxpayer Identification number(TIN) and Central Sales Tax(CST) fields. How can I do that using php?

I have to implement this validation in seller registration form in shopping cart.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php . first try to create regex and then test as per you requirement.

Comment: can you share format of Taxpayer Identification number and Central Sales Tax fields, It can be done by regex

Comment: @MangeshGhotage I didn't started the coding yet, for pan number verification i have just found the link that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969572/how-to-validate-pan-no-and-bank-account-number-using-php], like this may i have for tin or cst ?

Comment: @Shahbaz The format of TIN is 33392964391 and CST is 1280154 and Its a real one. Please do the needful

Comment: You need to use php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php method If you are still unsure how to do it you can comment here.

Comment: @Shahbaz yes how do we use preg-match to verify registered tin and cst ? like this http://www.tinxsys.com/TinxsysInternetWeb/searchByTin_Inter.jsp site,.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [preg-match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to achieve your results

as you have mentioned in your comments TIN is 33392964391 exactly 11 digits you can do it in the following way in PHP

```
function validateFieldByRegex($regex , $string)
{
    if ( !preg_match($regex, $string) ) {
        echo 'incorrect string';
    } else {
        echo 'correct string';
    }
}

validateFieldByRegex('/^[1-9]([0-9]{1,10}$)/', '33392964390');
validateFieldByRegex('/^[1-9]([0-9]{1,6}$)/', '1280154');
```

Comment: thank u, is there any way to find whether the tin and cst is registered or not ? like this - http://www.tinxsys.com/TinxsysInternetWeb/searchByTin_Inter.jsp

Comment: you can run a query to find that it is registered or not If you want more help you can contact me.

Answer (score 1):

Indian TIN number consists of 11 digit numerals and will be unique throughout the country. First two characters will represent the State Code as used by the Union Ministry of Home Affairs.

**RegEx** -

```
^(3[0-5]|[012][0-9]|[1-9])\d{9}$
```

**Matches**     starting with 01 to 35

**Non-Matches** starting with 0 or above 36

Check test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/ToPbwy/1)

Refer [here](http://www.taxalertindia.com/2010/01/what-is-tin-tin-structure-and-different.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to validate tin from India and other countries you could do it [here](https://tin-check.com/)

They have [API](https://api.tin-check.com/) that return response in json.

May be a goode solution if you need tin check for more countries. They perform for more than 100 countries.